# Is it possible to sort visual's data in power bi embedded?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

My report page has multiple visuals and I want to sort data in few visuals in descending order based on column value. I want to know if this is possible and how to do it?

Comment: This seems trivial. What have you tried? Have you tried clicking the header?

Answer (score 0):

To sort the visual's data in descending order based on column value:
a. First embed the report then get all the pages from the report.
b. Now get all the visuals of the current active page and then find your required visual.
c. Send a request to sort the data(described below).

Please follow the below code snippet:

1. Get a reference to the `HTML` element that contains the embedded report:

```js
const embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
```

2. Embed the `report`:

```js
const report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfig);
```

3. Get all the pages:

```js
const pages = await report.getPages();
```

4. Get the current active page:

```js
const activePage = pages.find(function (page) { 
       return page.isActive 
});
```

5. Get all the visuals:

```js
const visuals = await activePage.getVisuals();
```

6. Get the target visual (replace "VisualContainer6" with required visual name):

```js
const visual = visuals.find(function (visual) { 
      return visual.name === "VisualContainer6" 
});
```

7. The SortDirection enum defines the sort direction as Ascending or Descending:

```js
enum SortDirection {
    Ascending = 1,
    Descending = 2
}
```

8. Set the required field or column name and add the direction:

```js
const request = {
    orderBy: {
        table: "SalesFact",
        measure: "Total Category Volume"
    },
    direction: models.SortDirection.Descending
};
```

9. Sort the visual's data by `sortBy`:

```js
await visual.sortBy(request);
```

Output before sorting:

[image]

Output after sorting:

[image]

Please find reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/sort-visuals-by

Answer (score -1):

Sorting data on a visual is straightforward. Table visual is the simplest of them all. Click a header of a column that you want to sort, and you'll be good to go.

[image: screenshot - sorting in Power BI table visual]

Other types of visual have a small ellipsis icon in top right corner. Menu that opens when you click it has various sorting possibilities. Use Sort By option:

[image: screenshot - sorting in power BI visual]